# How to count the each number of row within a array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like-
[1 2 3 3 3;1 2 2 5 5]
From this matrix, I want to calculate in matlab that in each row how many numbers of 1 2 3 and 5?
The result will be -
1 1 2;
1 2 2

I have tried with  numberof1=sum(a(1:ac,:)==1); but this is valid if there is only one row but in my case there are multiple rows so i need to check every rows.

I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `==1` on the entire matrix A, and then sum along the rows. As in `sum(a==1,2);` (see [sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) documentation).